# CI: How can I get the data passed from View to the other View

Tags: codeigniter, for-loop, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

I am able to fetch the data in the loop on my **FirstView.php**. Along with the data fetched, there is `$i` value and the radio button value in the loop. So when the user selects the radio button and submits the forms, I want the value of the radio button and `$i` to be passed to **SecondView.php** to show what service has been selected. But, *I am only able to get the last value* in the loop displayed on my **SecondView.php**.

**FirstView.php**

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open('Bookings/Booking'); ?>       
<table class='table table-hover'>
    <thead class='thead-light'>
        <tr>
            <th scope='col'></th>
            <th scope='col'>Options Without Possessions</th>
            <th scope='col'></th>
            <th scope='col'></th>
            <th scope='col'></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        $i = 1;
        foreach ($quotes_fetched as $row_quotes_fetched) { 
        echo "   
        <tr>
            <th scope='row'>$i <input type='hidden' name='test' id='test' value='".$i."'size='1'/></th>
            <td>".$row_quotes_fetched->ori."</td>
            <td>". $row_quotes_fetched->dest ."</td>
            <td>$". round($row_quotes_fetched->sellcost, 2)."</td>
            <td><input type='radio' name='Bk_Option' id='Bk_Option_0' class = 'Bk_OptionSel' value='$row_quotes_fetched->sellcost' required /></td>
        </tr>"; $i++;}?>
    <thead class='thead-light'>
        <tr>
            <th scope='col'></th>
            <th scope='col'>Options With Possessions</th>
            <th scope='col'></th>
            <th scope='col'></th>
            <th scope='col'></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

**Controller (Booking.php)**

```
public function Booking(){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('Bk_Option', 'Pleae select one option','required');
    $service = $this->input->post('Bk_Option');
    $this->session->set_userdata('service_selected', $service);
    $hiddentext = $this->input->post('test');
    $this->session->set_userdata('selTest', $hiddentext);
    $data['Cont'] = $this->session->userdata('selTest');      
    $qid  = $this->session->userdata('qid');
    $this->load->view('SecondView'. $data);
}
```

**SecondView.php**

```
<?php echo 'Service Selected: '.$Cont ?>
```

**Results:**

Say for example there are **four rows** fetched on FirstView.php, and I select the second row and the value of **`$i = 2`** and value in the **`radio button = 200`** and click submit, it will show me the correct value of the radio button but the value of **`$i is 4`**.

Comment: um the $i variable is local to that view only. you seem like you need this value for some reason and as it is essentially `num_rows() + 1` you can just save that to a session variable in your controller for the first view. or make it a hidden input in the first view form.

Comment: @Alex I am saving it as a session and able to get the value in the secondview, however the value I get from $i is not correct value. It gives the value of the last result in the loop from the firstview.php

Comment: that is because with every foreach iteration you are overwriting the hidden input; the name and id **must** be unique for every element. otherwise you will just get the last element with the name `test`. there is no easy way around it, even if you make the element name unique per iteration.

Comment: then  how would I get it unique? As the records fetching in a loop and is there any way around?

Comment: with ajax this would be rather simple as you can just add a `data-` attribute and therefore, essentially, submit 2 values for 1 input. however with a traditional form you'd have to somehow relate the hidden input value with the radio value (can't think of an easy way to do this). would be easier to have a  query in 2nd controller to use the radio value to get the position and add 1 as you want `$i = 1` where normally is 0. are you running jquery?

Comment: that sounds a bit of a mission. But I am not running any JQuery.

Comment: well you could also remove the hidden input and have the radio value to `$value__$i` and use `__` to separate out the value and $i.

Comment: Alright, I could try this __

Comment: yea or any other unique marker. explode would be a quick and dirty way e.g. `$postvar  = explode('__', $post); $postvar[0] /* your value */ $postvar[1] /* your $i */`

Comment: I have this line now `<input type='radio' name='Bk_Option' id='Bk_Option_0' class = 'Bk_OptionSel' value='".$row_quotes_fetched->sellcost." ". $row_quotes_fetched->ori." to ".$row_quotes_fetched->dest."' required />`  and I want to separate `->sellcost`, `->ori` and `->dest` and save it as separate as I will have some if conditions on it. So how can I explode this?

Comment: Same way as I explained before, put a unique identifier between the strings. Still alot better to just send the id and get all details that way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180396/discussion-between-user10345537-and-alex).

Answer (score 0):

1. add data-id="$i" to radio button
2. Make JavaScript function call on click radio input and store data-id with that radio to hidden input(hidden input should be outside of foreach loop)
   3.jquery is required